# AS3 PNG Encoder?

Tags: actionscript-3, encoding, png, bitmapdata

Is there a way to encode bitmap data into PNG for use with a `FileReference.Save()` method in AS3? I assume I need an encoder library.

Where can I get a library that encode BitpmapData into PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

There are probably other solutions, but this is widely used and well tested. I've used it myself on several occasions without issue.

Comment: Will this work for offline distribution? (For example, CD distros of a projector.)

Comment: For sure, its entirely written in AS3

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. Looks good. I gotta figure out how to get the bitmapData into the encoder, but so far so good.

Answer (score 6):

Shameless plug!

I just wrote a new PNG encoder called PNGEncoder2. It's extremely fast, offers three compression levels, supports huge images, and offers true asynchronous encoding (no pause at the end during the compression step).

More details, including usage examples and the full feature list, can be found in the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/cameron314/PNGEncoder2#readme). I also wrote a blog post about it, which includes a [benchmark](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2011/a-better-png-encoder-for-flash#results) comparing it to other encoders (including Adobe's and blooddy's).

Answer (score 2):

I've been using blooddy_crypto.swc which you can read about and download here: http://va.lent.in/blog/2010/06/23/100x-times-faster-md5-and-more/ - I found it approx. 3 times faster than the adobe PNGEncoder.