# How to save a Image to PNG format?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder4.5

Now Im saving to text format, and I got a error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at SaveImage/onClick()[/Users/VVT/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/SuperDraw/src/SaveImage.as:40] 
                                                                                                    I wanna change my code so I can save to PNG format?

```
public class SaveImage extends Sprite

{
    private var btnSave:buttonSave;
    //private var ba:ByteArray;
    private var file:FileReference;

    public function SaveImage()
    {
        // Skapar min knapp.
        var btnSave:buttonSave = new buttonSave();
        addChild(btnSave);
        btnSave.x = 400;
        btnSave.y = 440;

        btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        var file:FileReference = new FileReference();           
    }

    private function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        //var ba:ByteArray = file.encode(bitmapData);
        //file.save(file);
        file.save("some text. \nsome more text", "actionsnippet.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211852/as3-png-encoder

Comment: ok, the link help me a little bit. But I still can not save to PNG, using my btnSave ...

Comment: hope this helps: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Save_a_local_image_file__JPEG_or_PNG__from_an_imag-8406.html

Comment: ok, the link help me a little bit. But I still can not save to PNG, using my btnSave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a property named `file`, yet you are creating and initializing a local variable with the same name in this line of your constructor:

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
```

Don't worry, those mistakes happen. Remove the `var` and type to get rid of that null reference error.

```
file = new FileReference();
```

---

To save the image as png, the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) library, which is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211921/897024) of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211852/as3-png-encoder) linked in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768481/how-to-save-a-image-to-png-format#comment10929613_8768481), looks quite promising. Import the library and let it encode your bitmapdata:

```
file.save(PNGEncoder.encode(bitmapData));
```

Comment: How to install as3corelib, I been testing and I can not understand how I should install the as3corelib. Can somebody explain/show me how to do that?

Comment: @VVTinho I guess you have to add it the `as3corelib.swc` to the library paths in the ide. I never used Flashbuilder so I don't know how it's done exactly. A quick and dirty way would be simply to copy the `com` directory (found in `src` in the zip file) into your project's root directory.

Comment: `BitmapData.encode()` can encode PNG too, and doesn't require any external libraries. You can also decode PNG using `Loader`. JPEG is supported too.